# How to plot Area Fraction as a fuction of Area in Binary Image with MatPlotLib?

Tags: matplotlib

Suppose I have a B&W binary image, such as the one attached below.
[Sample binary image used for analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfXAD.png)
The black regions are referred to as "particles." I know the areas and area fractions of each individual particle. I can construct a histogram binning the areas to get a count of each size based on my bin width. I want to take this a step further and plot the area function as a function of area bins, in essence figuring out how much each "particle size bin" contributes to total area of black space in the image. i.e. what percentage of total black area is made up of small particles, how much is made up of large particles, etc. Obviously a bar chart of some kind, but I don't know how to draft this up in Python.
I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here.

I attempted to qcut my array with area values into 50 bins, but was unable to figure out how to plot area fraction on the y-axis of a bar chart.